# Count number of violations in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, count, join

This problem is driving me nuts since I know the root cause of the issue but don't know how it can be fixed. Here's what I'm trying to solve
I have 3 tables:

_Table "Publisher": Columns are "ASIN", "publisher_ID", etc. The ASIN will be the primary key of course because 1 publisher can have a lot of books

_Table "Rights": rights violation. Columns are  "ASIN", "type of violations", "action" (either 'fail' or 'pass'), etc. So 1 ASIN can be actioned multiple time (Ex: ASIN A - Trademark - Fail, ASIN A - Copyright - Pass, etc.)

_Table "Escalations": escalation we received. Columns are "ASIN", etc.

Of course these tables have more columns but the ones listed are more relevant.

Now my purpose is when I put in a publisher ID, I want the query to give me the count of escalations we have received for that publisher, and the count of books from that publisher that fail rights

So this is what I have

```
    SELECT publisher_ID,
           num_of_rights_violations,
           num_of_escalations 
    FROM (SELECT p.publisher_ID,
                 sum(if(e.asin = p.asin, 1, 0)) as num_of_escalations,
                 sum(if(r.asin = p.asin and r.acion = 'fail'),1,0) as num_of_rights_violations
          FROM publisher p
          LEFT JOIN rights r
               ON r.asin = p.asin
          LEFT JOIN escalations e
               ON e.asin = p.asin
          WHERE p.publisher_ID = 'xxx'
          GROUP BY p.publisher_ID) a
```

However, the result is very weird. So for this publisher, there are only 3 ASINs that fail for rights violation. These 3 ASINs were escalated to us 6 times total. This publisher was escalated 18 times total. So, the right results should be : **xxx - 3 - 18**. But it gave me **xxx - 6 - 18**. So my doubt is for some reason for num_of_rights_violation, my joint functions returned the total of escalations the ASINs, found in table r and action is 'fail' (3), received (6).

Can someone please help me fix this?

Regards,

Comment: The join of publish to rights and publish to escalations is causing your count to be artificially inflated.  you have to count first then join.

Comment: Can you please help me do that then? I know it should be an easy fix but it has been killing me for the last 2 days :)

Comment: "group by" statement should be included in the inner query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to get the counts before the joins as the 2nd join is artificially increasing the counts.

so we would have

```
Publisher  escalation right
1          A          Z
1          A          Y
1          A          X
2          A          1
2          B          1
```

So you're counting A thrice for publisher 1 in the above when you only want to count it once. and you'd be counting right twice for publisher 2 when you only want one because of the 2 escalations from the join.

You get the counts from escalation and right FIRST and then join. (preferred imo)

Alternatively, If we distinct escalation an right we might get the correct counts (assuming we are counting the PK of each table)  more co

```
SELECT p.publisher_ID
     , num_of_escalations,
     , num_of_rights_violations
FROM publisher p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT asin, count(*) as Num_of_Escalations 
           FROM rights where acion = 'fail' 
           GROUP BY asin)  r
   ON r.asin = p.asin
LEFT JOIN (SELECT asin, count(*) as num_of_rights_violations 
           FROM escalations 
           GROUP BY asin) e
   ON e.asin = p.asi
WHERE p.publisher_ID = 'xxx'
```

another way which may work would be to count the distinct values from the Primary key of each table.

```
SELECT p.publisher_ID
     , count(distinct e.pk) as num_of_escalations --assume each table has a pk change the pk to the primary key field of table
     , count(distinct r.pk) as num_of_rights_violations --assume each table has a pk change the pk to the primary key field of table
FROM publisher p
LEFT JOIN rights r
  ON r.asin = p.asin
 AND r.acion='fail' --moved limit to join 
LEFT JOIN escalations e
  ON e.asin = p.asin
WHERE p.publisher_ID = 'xxx'
GROUP BY p.publisher_ID
```

Alternative engines support window functions which could do this as well, or you could simulate them using user variables; but I think one of the above concepts should work.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Right now it works. Indeed, my query is joining a lot of tables so let's see If I can mimic this. Hopefully I can.

Thanks a lot :)